# How to inject or send service from inherited component to base component

Tags: angular, typescript, oop

I wanna create baseComponent for use all existed component to inherit this.
now I wanna the best way to inject service to baseComponent and I have two solutions for this.
first: send service for ctor to the super component like below code, that this way causes to change all child's component in body and method's.but this way work correctly

IService.ts

```
    export interface IService {}
```

ICrudService.ts

```
    export interface ICrudService extends IService {
    getById(id: any): Promise<any>;
    getList(): Promise<any>;
    getListByParam(fields?: Array<string>,rel?: Array<ItemRelValue>,statePaging?: State,filterSingle?: Array<any>,extraParams?: any,groups?: Array<any>): Promise<any>;
    update(item: any): Promise<any>;
    remove(id: any): Promise<any>;
    add(item: any): Promise<any>;
    }
```

BaseComponent.ts

```
    export abstract class BaseComponent{
      public gridData: any = {  };
      public state: State = {  };
      protected param: Array<string> = [];
      protected rel: Array<ItemRelValue> = [];
      protected filter: Array<any> = [];
      protected groups: Array<Group> = [];
      protected aggregate: Array<Aggregate> = [];

      constructor(public title: Title,public router: Router,public toaster?: ToasterService,public service:IService) {   }

      protected getDataByParam() {
        this.service
               .getListByParam(this.param,this.rel,this.state,this.filter,null,this.groups)
          .then(response => {
            if (response.total) {
              this.gridData.total = Number(response.total);
            }
            response.data.forEach((item, index) => {
              this.rowReview(item);
              item.rowNumber = rowNumber++;
              this.gridData.data.push(item);
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            this.toaster.popAsync("error", "خطا", error.message);
          });
      }

      protected abstract rowReview(item?);
      // Todo: chane top review response

      public exportToExcel = (): Promise<any> => {
        return this.service
                  .getListByParam(this.param,this.rel,this.state,this.filter,null,this.groups      )
          .then(response => {
            response.data.forEach((item, index) => {
              this.rowReview(item);
              item.rowNumber = index + 1;
            });
            return Promise.resolve(response);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            this.toaster.popAsync("error", "خطا", error.message);
            return Promise.reject({});
          });
      };
    }
```

and one of the inherited component's

```
    export class EducationalPostComponent extends BaseComponent {

      constructor(
        public title: Title,
        public router: Router,
        public toaster: ToasterService,
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private postsService: PostsService
      ) {
        super(title, router, toaster,postsService);
        }
    }
```

the second way: I wanna use generic mode or the best way to decrease changes in our project, send service from generic mode like type(I'm not happy with this model) like below code

export class EducationalPostComponent extends Base2 {
  //endregion

BaseComponent.ts

```
    export abstract class BaseComponent<T>{
      ...
      public service :any={} as T;
      constructor(
        public title: Title,
        public router: Router,
       public toaster?: ToasterService,
       ) {
       }
       ...
```

}

and one of the inherited component's

```
    export class EducationalPostComponent extends Base2<EducationalPostService> {
      constructor(
        public title: Title,
        public router: Router,
        public toaster: ToasterService,
        private fb: FormBuilder
      ) {
        super(title, router, toaster);
         }
    }
```

but this way don't work and have error on runtime.

I'm confused.
best way to inject dynamically service and how to work in parentComponent.

Comment: do you used from angular static injector ?

Comment: we have very service with a different name, how to inject dynamically services?